# 3 way Switched outlet 30v open ground + neutral

Tags: electrical

I’m swapping out old switches and receptacles and am working on a 3-way switched receptacle now.

Odd thing is when both switches are off I get 0v on the outlet, when 1 is on I get 120v but when they are opposing I get 30v open neutral + ground.

Comment: Usually with three ways, opposing(one up, one down) means off, both up or down means on.  Pictures showing how the wires are connected(with power off) at the outlet and both switches will help(maybe).

Comment: Do you have a LoZ setting on your voltmeter, or a lamp you can plug into the outlet with a socket/bulb T adapter + bulb in it for that matter?